# Boost binding error in completion handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I encountered an binding error

/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457: error: invalid use of void expression

My program is about an asynchronous action using a callback handler as following:

```
template<typename Handler>
void async_monitor(Handler handler) {
    stream_descriptor_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
            boost::bind(&dir_monitor_impl::handle_monitor<Handler>, shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    handler));
}//IF I remove this code, the compilation success
```

And the handler declaration:

```
template<typename Handler>
void handle_monitor(boost::system::error_code &ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred, Handler handler){
}
```

Finally, these asychronous action is used as follwowing:

```
template <typename Handler> 
void start_async_monitor(implementation_type &impl, Handler handler) 
{ 
    //this->async_monitor_io_service_.post(monitor_operation<Handler>(impl, this->get_io_service(), handler));
    impl->async_monitor(handler);
}
```

Could you guys help me explain this error, Thanks so much!

Comment: could you post the full error message?

Comment: @rhalbersma:it's so long to post here. Compliler does not show exactly   about the error.

Comment: /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, file_handler, boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::dir_monitor_event>) (file_handler*&, const boost::system::error_code&, const long unsigned int&)’

Answer (score 2):

The handler signature must be the following (pay attention to **const**):

`void handle_monitor(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred, Handler handler)`

Comment: +1 well spotted on the missing `const`. I had been staring at it for 5 minutes and missed it.

Comment: @lgor: thanks you! I solved the problem. The error is the argument handler in my binding function is bounded before ==> nested binding ==> error.

Comment: @khanhhh89 if an answer answers your question, please press "accept" to accept it - this way the question gets marked as answered and it would help other users searching similar question.